# Import function from another page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import, react-hooks

I need to call function resetToken() from another page when i click on button.
resetToken() should change useState to generate new code. I don't know how to import this function to another page and use it.

I have import
`import Captcha from '../../../components/Captcha/Captcha';` and displayed with `<Captcha/>` in `return( ... )`

So when i click on button I need to call function resetToken() to generate new code or call again import because I have in  `<Captcha/>`

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
            resetToken();
         },[]);
```

This code is Captcha.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './Captcha.css';

function Captcha({statusOfCaptcha}){
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [code, setCode] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(120);

    function resetToken(){
        //generate code
        var codeGenerated = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            codeGenerated += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        setCode(codeGenerated);
        //reset every 120 second
        setInterval(function(){
            var codeGenerated = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789";
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                codeGenerated += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            setCode(codeGenerated);
            setSeconds(120);
            setStatus(undefined);
            setText("");
         }, 120000);
         const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1);
          }, 1000);
          return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        resetToken();
     },[]);

  function checkCaptcha(e){
    if(e === code){
        setStatus(true);
        statusOfCaptcha(true);
    } else{
        setStatus(false);
        statusOfCaptcha(false);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='captcha'>
        <div className="background">
            <p onCopy={(e) => e.preventDefault()} className="unselectable">{code}</p>
            <a>{seconds}</a>
        </div>
        <div className='input-captcha'>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zadejte kód" value={text} onChange={(e) => {checkCaptcha(e.target.value); setText(e.target.value)}}/>
            {status === false && (<i class='bx bx-x text-color-red'></i>)}
            {status === true && (<i class='bx bx-check text-color-green'></i>)}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Captcha;
```

This code is index.jsx

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Captcha from '../../../components/Captcha/Captcha';
   
    function Index() {

      function change(){
          //here i need to call function from Captcha.jsx - resetToken();
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <Captcha statusOfCaptcha={resCaptchaData}/>
          <button onclick={change}>Reset captcha code</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default Index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use a custom hook, to store your state, and `resetToken` function, So you can use it in multiple places.

For more resources about custom hooks.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: And is it possible to somehow call the function from one page so that it is executed on the other page and I didn't have to move the data somehow?

Comment: I don't recommend this approach, but you can create a new file that exports an object that has a property = null let's call it `funcRef`, then in you component, import this object and assign `funcRef` to your `resetToken` function, and then you can use the `funcRef` anywhere because it holds `setToken` function referance.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand, i edited this post and uploaded full code and i think now you can understand me better what i need. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Please check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-bouman-jtpvc2

Comment: Oh, yes now I understand and know how to do it, thank you for your time you help me lots of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways

for example you can use state manager like context api or redux.
In order to have access to your states or functions everywhere and in all pages and components

Or you can put the resetToken function in the parent component and have access to it in the child components.

```
    export const ParentComponent = (children) => {
           function resetToken {
             ....
           }
    return (
       <Recapcha resetToken={resetToken} />
    )
   }
    
   



const Recapcha = ({resetToken}) => {
  
          return (...)
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use it somehow but I'm getting errors, do you think you could please show me an example in that code with my names and useState?

Comment: You must pass all the state and function to the parent component for access

Comment: So all states i need to move to ParentComponent ?

Comment: Yes, because your function (Reset Token()) is in the parent component.